# Given a Numpy array, how to calculate the percentile of each of the array elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array like this:

```
import numpy as np

arrx = np.array([0, 5, 10])
print(np.percentile(arrx, 100))
```

Which returns a single scalar: the element that more closely matches the percentile I specified as a second argument. In this case, `10`.

I would like however to get an equivalent array which gives the percentile of each element, for example:

```
# do something
> [0, 50, 100]
```

Where the first element is at the 0 percentile, 5 is at 50%, and so forth.

How can this be done efficiently with numpy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply standardize by the max:

```
arrx/arrx.max()*100
```

Or maybe by the min/max:

```
(arrx-arrx.min())/(arrx.max()-arrx.min())*100
```

Output: `array([  0.,  50., 100.])`

Comment: Ha yes! I always forget I can do these vectorized operations - thank you! Will accept the answer in a few mins and SO lets me.